# How do I translate string inside jQuery script with WPML?

Tags: jquery, localization, plugin-wpml

I've made this script for changing some colors on a custom element. My problem is that I can't find a way to localize the links in the href attribute.

Is there an easy way for me to do this?

```
/* Wilfa Svart Color Change Function */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.precision-link-color-1').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       jQuery(".precision-image-link").attr("href", "http://newsite.wilfa.no/produkter/kaffetrakter/svart-presisjon-aluminium/");
       jQuery('.wilfa-precision-product-content').css('background', 'url(../wp-content/themes/wilfa/images/coffee-brewer.jpg) no-repeat center center');
  });
  jQuery('.precision-link-color-2').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       jQuery(".precision-image-link").attr("href", "http://newsite.wilfa.no/produkter/kaffetrakter/svart-presisjon-sort/");
       jQuery('.wilfa-precision-product-content').css('background', 'url(../wp-content/themes/wilfa/images/coffee-brewer-black.jpg) no-repeat center center');
  });
});
```

Specifically, this line:

```
jQuery(".precision-image-link").attr("href", "http://newsite.wilfa.no/produkter/kaffetrakter/svart-presisjon-sort/");
```

**UPDATE**

Here's my attempt with an else/if statement to get the lang attr(This works):

```
/* Wilfa Svart Color Change Function */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var theLanguage = jQuery('html').attr('lang');

    jQuery('.precision-link-color-1').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(theLanguage == 'en-US') {
            jQuery(".precision-image-link").attr("href", "http://alternative-link.com/");
        } else {
            jQuery(".precision-image-link").attr("href", "http://original-link.com/");
        }
        jQuery('.wilfa-precision-product-content').css('background', 'url(../image.jpg) no-repeat center center');
  });
    jQuery('.precision-link-color-2').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(theLanguage == 'en-US') {
            jQuery(".precision-image-link").attr("href", "http://alternative-link.com");
        } else {
            jQuery(".precision-image-link").attr("href", "http://original-link.com");
        }
        jQuery('.wilfa-precision-product-content').css('background', 'url(../image.jpg) no-repeat center center');
  });
});
```

Comment: If you want to keep on using this static way for writing your url's, you could sniff the lang attribute value of html-element and output a different url for different lang values. But why are you writing href's with jquery in the first place? It seems a bit funny.

Comment: That seems viable, although I'm not sure how to sniff the lang attribute. Yes, it is definitely a bit funny, but it works as intended, except for the language part..

Comment: Why do you need WPML for that?

Comment: @toscho it's just the plugin I'm using for localization on my site, I thought it would be appropriate to mention

Comment: Get the lang attribute value with jQuery .attr, store it as a variable and do a simple if else statement to output different href for different values. You could also output the href with php from stored custom field etc. or use icl_language_code to output different static values for different languages. But to keep it simple, just get lang value from html and go with that.

Comment: Thank you @jounileander. It's working now, I'll update the question with the correct information. I had a problem where only the else statement would work, until I realized `lang` was `en-US` instead of `en`.

Comment: Glad to help. As this was just a quick and ugly way to do this, you might want to try wp_localize_script as JMau pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

To translate something in your js you can use [wp_localize_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) really handy :

```
 $translation_array = array( 'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate' ), 'a_value' => '10' );
 wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );
```